# Can I use a typing.Callable type to annotate a function automatically? How?

Tags: python, python-typing

Suppose we define a type for a callback like so:

```py
CallbackFn = Callable[[str, str, int, int], None]
```

When I want to implement a callback function, and have external tools type-check it against `CallbackFn`, I have to annotate the types explicitly:

```py
def my_callback(s1: str, s2: str, i1: int, i2: int) -> None:
  ...
```

Is there any way that I can use the type hint defined in `CallbackFn` to annoate a function - something like `def my_callback(s1,s2,i1,i2) as CallbackFn:` - to avoid the explicit annotation work?

Comment: Yeah, I don't think there is any way in Python's type hinting system to do this.

Comment: It looks like the python community still don't have consensus about how to support this. I am wondering if other mordern languages, like typescript or kotlin, have addresssed such issue in their design.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of, but it's not recommended, or pretty. For example,

```
my_callback: CallbackFn = lambda s1, s2, i1, i2: <do the thing>
```

or if you're working with higher-order functions

```
my_callback: CallbackFn = compose(f, g)
```

for some `compose`, `f` and `g`.

You can of course also expose an API written in the standard style like this

```
my_callback: CallbackFn = _my_callback

def _my_callback(s1: str, s2: str, i1: int, i2: int) -> None: ...
```

All of these examples go against [the Python style guide](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) of using `def` over `lambda` for named functions.

Comment: It's a pitty that this doesn't work for named function.

Comment: Would it be possible to create a named function then call it inside the lambda?

Comment: @link89 what do you mean named? it is named `my_callback`

Comment: Hi @joel, I think the original question is about how to avoid repeating type annotation by re-using the typing information provided in `CallbackFn`, it's not about how to use `CallbackFn` to add a type hint to a variable.

Comment: @link89 yes i realise, but a function is a value, so I think they are not all that different. If you're asking "can I use `CallbackFn` in the `def` syntax for a function?", I'm essentially saying no, I don't think there is a way to do that

Answer (score 0):

This is quite easy to do with a no-op decorator.

```py
from collections.abc import Callable
from typing import Any, TypeAlias, TypeVar

CallbackFn: TypeAlias = Callable[[str, str, int, int], None]
Any4ParamCallableT = TypeVar("Any4ParamCallableT", bound=Callable[[Any, Any, Any, Any], None])

def asCallbackFn(f: Any4ParamCallableT, /) -> CallbackFn:
    """No-op decorator to impart typing to the function being decorated"""
    return f

@asCallbackFn
def my_callback(s1, s2, i1, i2):
    return
```

Here's a deliberate attempt to use wrong types in the return and parameter values:

```py
# mypy: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "None", variable has type "int") [assignment]
# mypy: Argument 1 to "my_callback" has incompatible type "int"; expected "str" [arg-type]
# mypy: Argument 2 to "my_callback" has incompatible type "int"; expected "str" [arg-type]
retval: int = my_callback(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

I don't really recommend trying to do what you're doing though, it's better to explicitly type each function. Among other things, you'll lose the ability to use keyword argument calling convention if you type things with `Callable[[<type>, ...], ...]` (you can use a callback protocol, but then that forces you to name all your callback functions with the same named arguments).